# Improving a flat table view

Tags: website-design, tables, first-impression, flat-design

I've been asked to improve a table view from where the main purpose  is to show details about a business agreements.

First at all, I was given this view:

[image]

So, I started to do some research on UX techniques and considering the flat design that is applied in this project and then after 2 days of work, I have come up with this:

[image]

As this is my first UX project and I'm a beginner at UX, I'm not sure if the way I'm re-doing this view is the correct. Do you consider this change to be an improvement?

Additionally, what could be a good UX book, for beginners?

Comment: You have asked two separate questions, one of which already has been a popular question asked previously, so try search for it in the questions. As for your initial question, it would help us to give you the best suggestions for improvement if you can tell us your rationale and thought process behind the design. One of the best ways to improve your UX skills is to consider WHY rather than HOW.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definitely an improvement, provided that you've Considered important columns to be seen by the user upfront 
1. You are not showering with the information
2. Due to collapse/expand drop-downs - you're adding Discover-ability.
3. The UI becomes less cluttered.

Additionally you can implement
2. Give an additional control to append more columns which are hidden
3. User can re-size the columns
4. User can rearrange the columns - they can drag & drop to arrange the sequence of columns as per there liking.
5. The setting are saved automatically.
6. First & important column is frozen & user can freeze/unfreeze columns
7. You can remove the drop-down sort arrows & show them only on rollover of the title - & the only one is seen which is sorted.

Here is an example
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/frozen-columns
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#progress-bar-pager

Answer (score 0):

You have reduced the number of columns visible in the table. Without a context, its hard to say if this is an improvement. It might be a good thing, provided the users of this table are happy to have those columns hidden. Also, I don't see a way to bring those columns back into view.

The three actions buttons are confusing to me. What do the green and the arrow buttons supposed to do?